# Disable console output from subprocess.Popen in Python

Tags: python, console, subprocess, popen

I run Python 2.5 on Windows, and somewhere in the code I have

```
subprocess.Popen("taskkill /PID " + str(p.pid))
```

to kill IE window by pid. The problem is that without setting up piping in Popen I still get output to console - SUCCESS: The process with PID 2068 has been terminated. I debugged it to CreateProcess in `subprocess.py`, but can't go from there.

Anyone knows how to disable this?

Comment: What is the problem with subprocess.Popen("taskkill /PID " + str(p.pid) + " > NUL")?

Comment: Maybe because python runs on Windows? It says that '>' is not a valid option of taskkill command

Comment: I tried that first, for some reason it doesn't parse correctly.
>>> ERROR: Invalid Argument/Option - '>'.
Type "TASKKILL /?" for usage.

That works on the cmd line though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
fh = open("NUL","w")
subprocess.Popen("taskkill /PID " + str(p.pid), stdout = fh, stderr = fh)
fh.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! This piece actually works. I completely forgot about NUL.

Comment: I think there's a race condition there — you may close the pipe before your subprocess has finished and cause it to terminate early.

Comment: @chrispy - you're correct, I think there should be a .communicate() in there

Comment: @chrispy,@orip: actually, isn't the answer to add `.wait()` to the subprocess line?

Comment: Just a silly question: I want to do the exact same thing, and I don't understand why stdout=None prevent the thread to display stuff...

Comment: You can better use: os.devnull instead of "NUL", because that is cross-platform. Windows uses: 'nul' and Linux uses: '/dev/null'.

Answer (score 18):

```py
from subprocess import check_call, DEVNULL, STDOUT

check_call(
    ("taskkill", "/PID", str(p.pid)),
    stdout=DEVNULL,
    stderr=STDOUT,
)
```

I always pass in tuples (or lists) to subprocess as it saves me worrying about escaping. check_call ensures (a) the subprocess has finished *before* the pipe closes, and (b) a failure in the called process is not ignored.

If you're stuck in python 2, subprocess doesn't provide DEVNULL. However, you can replicate it by opening `os.devnull` (the standard, cross-platform way of saying `NUL` in Python 2.4+):

```
import os
from subprocess import check_call, STDOUT

DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'wb')
try:
    check_call(
        ("taskkill", "/PID", str(p.pid)),
        stdout=DEVNULL,
        stderr=STDOUT,
    )
finally:
    DEVNULL.close()
```